# Postgres dump command works on the shell, but not when I add it to a crontab

Tags: postgresql, unix, cron

I've been trying to run the command

```
pg_dump -U database_username database_name > /path/to/directory/database_name.$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S").dump
```

And this command works when I do it from the command prompt, but it doesn't output anything when I put it in a crontab.  Why is that?

I also defined a `.pgpass` file in my home directory, which contains lines like

```
hostname:port:database_name:database_username:database_password
```

so when I run the command from the command prompt, it doesn't prompt me for a password.  I'm not sure if the crontab has access to that file or not.

Comment: Commands run by `cron` are, most annoyingly, run in an environment which is significantly different from your normal interactive shell environment.  There might be a different search path, the system-wide shell profile might not have been run, your own profile or bash_login might not have been run.  That makes this sort of problem frustratingly common.  You often have to contrive to explicitly run keep profile and/or login scripts for the benefit of your cron jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run your script as if you where connected directly to the server from *cron*, you should ***`source`*** for your env. variables to be set. E.g. say you're running on ksh with `pg_usr` user:

```
10 03 * * * source /home/pg_usr/.kshrc ; my_postgre_shell
```

Another thing is *cron* might not set the same `umask` as defaulted when you connect directly, resulting in different file access rights on the files generated by the *cron* session. So you must set also the desired `umask`:

```
10 03 * * * source /home/pg_usr/.kshrc ; umask 002 ; my_postgre_shell
```

Answer (score 0):

#!/bin/bash

export PGPASSFILE="/home/YOUR_LINUX_USER/.pg_pass"

... the rest of the script